# How did this 1x4 plate look like before modifying?

Tags: piece-information, part-identification

As you can see someone modified this 1x4 plate. Can you tell me which brick this was originally?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My guess is that it was a [Hinge Vehicle Roof Holder 1 x 4](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=879#T=P), but there are probably several pieces you could have modified to look like that.

Comment: This seems likely to be correct.  But it leads to other questions like... why would you go to that much work to end up with a 1x4 plate?

Comment: It looks pretty old... probably from back in the day when you didn't a magic machine that can deliver anything you want to your front door. Especially LEGO!!

Comment: @chicks I am interested in sets from the 80ties and 90ties, buying them used and on regular basis have to see in my used part inventory for single items. Right now i need 3 of those 1x4 plates white. I have to order them at Brinklink so I am thinking about using this item ;-)